# how to delete a row from the QListWidget in which the button was pressed

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qlistwidgetitem

how to delete a line from QListWidget in which the button was pressed? i know to delete some line ([foto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1Ns.png)) it is necessary to cause method removeItemWidget but for it it is necessary QListWidgetItem but I do not know how to receive it having QWidget which I received from sender ()

The code I use to create strings:

````
    QLayout* l = new QHBoxLayout;
    auto le=new QLineEdit;
    le->setMaximumWidth(250);
    l->addWidget( le );
    auto le2=new QLineEdit;
    l->addWidget( le2 );
    QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton( "Х" );
    btn->setObjectName(QString::number(ggg));
    connect( btn, SIGNAL( clicked() ), SLOT( close() ) );
    btn->setFixedWidth(22);
    l->addWidget( btn );
    wgt->setLayout( l );
    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem( ui->listWidget);
    item->setSizeHint( wgt->sizeHint() );
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item,wgt);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeItemWidget()` only removes the item from the view but it does not delete it so you will have a memory leak. I am not sure if this is what you want, I guess not. But to remove widget from the item, you can delete the widget and it is removed automatically. So the following code should delete the widget and the row as well. This is what I understand from your requirements.

```cpp
connect( btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [item, wgt]{ delete wgt; delete item; } );
```

Of course you can only place this line after line

```cpp
QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem( ui->listWidget);
```

I have not tested it, you may need to use `wgt->deleteLater();` instead of `delete wgt`.

Comment: this answer worked perfectly, without changes, but how we got [item, wgt] and where i can find out more ?

Comment: The expression `[item, wgt]{ delete wgt; delete item; }` is called "lambda" (which is term for anonymous function). The items in the square brackets are parameters to the lambda function which are "captured" from the current scope (the lambda can have also normal parameters but they are not used here). In this case these are the pointers to the widget and to the list item. And in the lambda, both the the objects pointed to by the two pointers get destroyed. Which basically removes them from the list widget without any memory leak.

Comment: You should definitely learn lambdas, they are really useful especially in combination with  `connect.